Saving data in an Excel file in anylogic
I am doing a ParametersVariation experiment. In each run I want to write into an Excel file data collected by an histogram data, but it only saves the data from the last run.
I have tried calling the function excel_file.writeFile(); at the end of each run but it still only saves the data from the last run.

you need to show us how you are saving the data in the histogram... you need to do it in the parameters variation experiment and not in the simulation experiment...
